# PHP MySQLi giving error with external connection but can connect from other sources

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm migrating servers from a shared hosting server to a VPS. As part of the transition I want to have the site as it's currently running start using the database on the new server before I fully switch the site and DNS records over.

The new server has mysql up and running and I can connect both local from the server, and I can connect as an external connection using Sequal Pro app on my iMac. When I use the same details to connect in my PHP script though on the shared hosting server I get a `(2002) Connection refusedDB: 0` error.

The PHP script looks like

```
$servername = "SERVERIP";
$usernamedb = "USERNAME";
$passworddb = "PASSWORD";
$dbname = "DBNAME";

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $usernamedb, $passworddb, $dbname, 3306);

if ($conn->connect_errno) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: (" . $conn->connect_errno . ") " . $conn->connect_error;
}
```

I've checked `/var/log/mysql/error.log` and there isn't any issues being logged. It has to be something with the PHP connection rather than the VPS/MySQL side because I can connect from my home internet connection using Sequal Pro without issue so the server is definetly allowing connections from external sources using those username, password, and db name details.

I added the port number to the `new mysqli` statement in case the shared hosting had the default setup differently but it doesn't make a difference with or without it.

Comment: Are you running SELinux (try `sestatus`)? If so, also try `sudo setenforce 0` to temporarily disable enforcement.

Comment: Try the connection using shell command-line mysql from the shared host to the VPS database.  You sometimes get better error messages that way.  That also tests it without PHP in the mix.

Comment: Did you already set the bind-address parameter in the my.cnf to 0.0.0.0

Comment: @YouneL Yeah; like I said external connections don’t seem to be an issue as I can connect from my home network to the VPS, I just can’t connect from the shared hosting.

Comment: Are the socket values the same in both configs?

Comment: @bishop SELinux isn't installed yet.

Comment: @saswanb Via command-line the error changes to `2003` and also outputs `'IPOFREMOTE' (111 "Connection refused")`

Comment: IPTables? Try `sudo service iptables stop` (or equivalent).

Comment: @bishop Nope, the only security at the moment is `ufw` but even disabling that doesn't change anything.

Comment: Well, we know that it fails from the command line on the client box, but works from the command line (GUI, technically) on your personal box. Thus, it must be a system/OS level setting on the client box other than SELinux or IPTables or a router/firewall between your client box and the server. Time to break out lower level (eg, IP) tools.

Comment: Please post the VPS database granted permissions

Comment: @bishop I got in touch with the shared hosting provider it it seems they were blocking the connection at the router level. They have unblocked it and it works now. Do you want to turn that into an answer (check security + check with host) and I can mark it correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the comments, we know that it fails from the command line on the client box, but works from the command line (GUI, technically) on your personal box. We also know from these comments that it's not SELinux or IPTables. Thus, it must be either:

- system/OS level setting on the client box other than SELinux or IPTables, or
- router/firewall between your client box and the server.

Time to break out lower level (eg, IP) tools. Or, as you discovered, contact the upstream network administrator.

In the words of a Certain Famous Detective:

> Once you eliminate the impossible, whatever remains, no matter how improbable, must be the truth.